# Best development platform out of HAL/Bare Metal/RTOS/Other OS

Tags: stm32

I have just startedworking on STM32 (STM32F407VET6 Board) and successfully implemented some basic LED patterns using the HAL drivers.

I would like to hear suggestions/advices on which software environment I should start developing my applications/projects which will be advantageous as a long term skill development.

I have researched a bit and the available options I found were:

STM32 provided HAL drivers

Free RTOS

MBED

LINUX

Bare Metal way

Any other OS/library/environment

Any advice will be appreciated. I am also open to work on multiple environments.

Edit: I am asking for ways on to program the STM32. (Not just the selection of IDE)

Comment: This question is off-topic

Comment: Furthermore a STM32F4 is clearly not designed to run Linux (it has no MMU) even if a modified version of Linux has been ran on it IIRC

Answer (score -1):

If you are working on Windows I would recommend the STM32CubeIDE.

This is a Eclipse based IDE that includes the HAL generation from ST and the gcc compiler, linker and debugger.

Since embedded programming is always cross-compiling it is not so important if you are using Windows or Linux (I guess Mac is similar, but I have none :-) )

The HAL is a easy way to get several things working, but you should also have a look at the LL (LowLevel) Library that also comes with the Project Generator in the STM32CubeIDE.

Comment: You mean I should try to stay close to Bare Metal Way (knowing LL drivers along with HAL)?
And any views on RTOS or other OSes out there for STM32?
Thank you so much for the answer though.

Comment: With the Cube tool you could include several "high level" module like RTOS or SD support into your project (they all depend on the HAL).